# Accuracy in combination with MSE

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [TensorFlow documentation for Accuracy metrics](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Accuracy) seems to suggest an examples with 'mse'. I tested this on a regression examples and indeed found the accuracy values corresponding with the loss progress. I found many sources declaring accuracy as useless if used in combination with MSE. Can someone explain what keras/TF is computing in this case and can it be seen as useful?

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you give links/DOIs to the correspoding papers related to `I found many sources declaring accuracy as useless if used in combination with MSE` ? I guess the key point is hidden there.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question could be explained as follows:

In a regression problem target values are real values. Like:

```
targets = [12.32, -3.69, 47.26]
```

Using a model, which is compiled as:

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss='mse',
               metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])
```

we get the following predictions:

```
predicted= [12.1, -3.6, 48.09]
```

Computing loss using "mse" is clear.

But how "accuracy" will be computed?

Comment: Yes that's indeed the question I have. Thanks for improving!